# sklearn SimpleImputer Valueerror

Tags: python

I try to implement IsolationForest on a csv-file.
I import the data with

```
quelle = pd.read_csv('./x.csv',delimiter=";")
```

and it works fine.

The csv contains strings and NaN-values,

```
print(quelle.head)
0              1     17,1  64,64  ...  0x00000800,0x00000800     NaN  45286,4789
1              2     17,1  64,64  ...  0x00000800,0x00000800     NaN  45286,4789
2              3     17,1  64,64  ...  0x00000800,0x00000800     NaN  45286,4789
```

so I tried to use SimpleImputer, to impute these values

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='constant',fill_value="1")
quelle=imp.fit(quelle)
```

But then I get a ValueError

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=SimpleImputer(fill_value='1', strategy='constant').
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or a      
array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I think, there is a mistake at the line quelle=imp.fit(quelle), but I am not sure, what else would be possible.

Thx in advance

Comment: Can you please give us the output of `quelle.dtypes`

Comment: print(quelle.dtype)
Unnamed: 0      int64
ip.proto       object
ttl            object
frame.len       int64
ip.src         object
ip.dst         object
ip.len         object
ip.flags       object
eth.src        object
eth.dst        object
eth.type       object
vlan.id       float64
udp.port       object
dtype: object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you are overwirting your dataframe 'quelle' with model by using this line of code.

```
quelle=imp.fit(quelle)
```

Here fit method will return the model i.e imp (SimpleImputer's instance) itself. Now after overwriting your dataframe, if you run this line of code again, you will be getting the error you mentioned above. So just write this instead

```
imp.fit(quelle)
newquelle = imp.transform(quelle)
```

Comment: ok, then I get rid of the message, but the NaN entries are still there (if I understand the output)
imp.fit(quelle)
print(quelle.head)
0              1     17,1  64,64  ...  0x00000800,0x00000800     NaN  45286,4789
1              2     17,1  64,64  ...  0x00000800,0x00000800     NaN  45286,4789

Comment: I think you are not using imp.transform function for filling the dataframe. Use newquelledf = imp.transform(quelle) #after calling th fit method as above. Answer updated above